# Primefaces sidebar menu like facebook?

Tags: facebook, primefaces, menu

how is it possible to create a menu like facebook:
Like the attached picture with primefaces?

[image]

Comment: Well, using CSS, and possibly JavaScript. Which parts specifically do you need help with? Gradients? Interactivity?

Comment: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu.jsf then use styling to change it.

Comment: Yey, I saw primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu.jsf  already. But how can I add there the number on the right side?